# "grayed out" inside a python function, need solution

Tags: python, sockets

Pls check the code

```
from socket import *

address = ('192.168.1.213', 5000) 
client_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)


rec_data, addr = client_socket.recvfrom(2048)

def comConnect(): 
    data = "Blue"
    client_socket.sendto(data,address)
    rec_data, addr = client_socket.recvfrom(2048)
    print(rec_data)
```

Looking at the code here, inside the function the "addr" is 'grayed out' but outside the function its not. I know the "addr" is related to the socket library, is there a way to use it inside the function? Should I use global or nonlocal if I want to use it inside a function?

Comment: `addr` is presumably grayed-out because you never use its value.  In any case, the coloring of your source code is entirely a function of the IDE you're using, *not* Python itself.

Comment: The gray is showing the variable is assigned but never used.  You can put a line after the assignment containing just the variable name and the gray will probably go away.  But if you actually want it to appear outside the function, yes, global would be good to use.

Comment: you are correct the grayed-out is  just a color of the ide that means not in used. what I understand is that "addr" is not grayed-out outside the function because of the socket library, isn't it? the 'conn' is the new socket object usable to send/receive data on the connection, and 'addr' is the address bound to the socket on the other end?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `addr` is never referenced (used). This is because `addr` inside the function is a local variable and is never referenced inside the function.

Comment: I thought the addr is part of socket library that I imported from?  inside the function can I reference it from the socket library that I imported?

Comment: As an example, try making a global string variable and then first row of function try to print it.
you will get local variable 'varName' referenced before assignment